# htaccess different path for errordocument on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, errordocument

I am facing problem while editing .htaccess file for my custom error page.

While on live server, this works fine.

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?e=400
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?e=401
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php?e=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?e=404
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php?e=500
```

But on my localhost (WAMP) my site is located in a folder named sms under www directory. so I've to modify code to

```
ErrorDocument 400 /sms/error.php?e=400
ErrorDocument 401 /sms/error.php?e=401
....and so on for all files
```

Is there a simple way to handle this situation so that I dont have to edit these line every time... Thanks..

Comment: Move `error.php` to the parent directory is an apparently simple way.

Comment: I've already done that as a work around, but I thought the gurus here may come up with a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little bit late in the day, but I had a similar problem and solved it.

It's `DocumentRoot` setting (in Apache configuration) that was the culprit. It has to point to the folder your site resides both on local and remote machines. Apparently in your case it was not.

You could get this kind of error if (for example) your site resided in *sms* directory both on local and remote machines, and in both cases the directory itself resided in default document root directory. What caused the error is that default root directory often gets overriden on server, when configuring virtual hosts.

It could look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName yourdomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sms
</VirtualHost>
```

In this case default document root has been changed from default */var/www/html* to */var/www/html/sms* while on your local machine `DocumentRoot` is still set to the default value (whatever it is in WAMP).

As a solution you could create a virtual host with custom document root (that would point to the *sms* directory) on your local machine. It can be done by editing the *httpd-vhosts.conf* file (in which case you should also edit the *hosts* file on your machine). If you have only one site though, it would be simpler to change the default `DocumentRoot` setting in *httpd.conf* so that it points to the *sms* directory.